# Magento split payments for different items in same cart

Tags: magento, braintree

Here is the problem:
I have multiple suppliers of physical goods, each with their own bank account.
A user is able to order items from multiple suppliers in the same cart.
The payment from the user for each item needs to go into the relevant supplier's bank account - these transtactions will be handled by multiple separate Braintree accounts.

Is it possible to achieve this with Magento Enterprise Edition?

I was looking at a similar thread (https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6974/split-order-into-seperate-orders-and-calculate-shipping-seperately-with-ups-and) which is dealing with the shipping side of this problem but I am not sure if it can be adapted to also work with the payments?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hi Tim, I work at Braintree. This isn't possible with Magento / Braintree. If you're looking for other solutions, you can always [contact our support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Comment: Hi Tim you can use either magento marketplace module with braintree marketplace payment method or you can use marketplace split cart module as well 
https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Braintree-Payment-Gateway.html
https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Split-Cart.html . Thanks